# Performing the form redirect when using HTTP POST over HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, post, httpwebrequest

We were initially submitting login credentials via a form. Now we're trying to mimic the same behavior by using C# to programmatically submit the same login creds via HTTP POST using `HttpWebRequest`.

We know that we're sending in the data correctly, and that the web service is receiving and authenticating the login data smoothly.

The problem, however, is that when we're using the form for login, the web service automatically redirects the user on success. We can't seem to duplicate that somehow when using an `HttpWebRequest` because the user and the request exist on two different sessions (I think).

**How should I perform the redirect behavior on successful authentication when using** `HttpWebRequest`**?** When we redirect manually, we're treated as if we're not authenticated.

For point of illustration, my request code looks similar to the following:

```
// var data = some byte[] data

var request = 
    (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://domain.com/login.asp");

request.ContentType = "x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.ContentLength = data.Length;
request.Method = "POST";

using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream()) {
    stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
    stream.Close();
}

var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

I'm laying this out as an ASP.NET MVC 3 project, so this code more or less appears in a controller action.

Comment: You aret sending your authentication ticket cookie(s) back to the server. That's how it knows you are logged in.

Comment: are you sending the cookies returned from the authentication request in the new request (to the redirected URL)?

Comment: That's exactly the point: I don't know how to do that. :D The cookies passed back with the `HttpWebRequest` are `System.Net.Cookie`, and the cookies with the standard MVC are `System.Web.HttpCookie`. I know that this is probably something simple that's just eluding me, but I couldn't figure out how to merge the web request cookies with the MVC cookies. Be gentle. :D